# How can one calculate Load Regulation for a temperature sensor?

Tags: sensor, temperature, load, units

I am wondering how to calculate the Load Regulation of a temperature sensor. For example [ADI's TMP37](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/TMP35_36_37.pdf)?

I know how to calculate % Load Regulation from [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_regulation), but not sure how to get to the mC/uA units?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It's related by the conversion factor of the sensor: 20 mV/degree, according to the front page of the datasheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datasheet for the part gives a plot of the typical load regulation as a function of temperature:

[image]

I'll take the value to be about 10 \$\mathrm{m}^\circ\mathrm{C}/\mu{}\mathrm{A}\$, since that's a bit higher than the given value over a wide temperature range. The datasheet also specifies that the output "scale factor" (pg 3 of the datasheet) of the TMP37 is 20 mV / degree C. Finally they specify a maximum output current of 50 uA.

\$50 \mu{}\mathrm{A}\times10\mathrm{m}^\circ\mathrm{C}/\mu{}\mathrm{A}\times20\mathrm{mV}/^\circ\mathrm{C}\$ gives about 10 mV error in voltage terms at the maximum specified load current.

Comment: How can I get that 10mC/uA value if I only made two measurements. One at no load, and one with full load at 30C and then again at 100C. I am basically trying to back track to the datasheet itself without relaying on it.